# if statement inside while loop is not working

Tags: php

This is a login php code that allows different users to login and use the application

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("sg",$con);


if(isset($_POST['uid'])){ $username = $_POST['uid']; } 

if(isset($_POST['pwd'])){ $password = $_POST['pwd']; } 





error_reporting(0);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT username,password from user where username = '$username' and password='$password'");
```

I want to check if a user exists and then open different pages for different users.In all three cases the page is redirected to Analyst.php

```
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))     

        {

if($username='operations')
{
                 header("Location: view3.php");
}

if($username='finance')
{
         header("Location: view3.php");
}

if($username='Analyst')
{
         header("Location: Analyst.php");
}

}           
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid userID or password ');window.location=\"home.html\";</script>";    


 ?>
```

Comment: `if($username='operations')` is assignment `if($username=='operations')` is comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two `=` signs:

```
if($username == 'finance')
```

A single `=` will assign a value to `$username`. In order to assess the value, you should use `==`.

Better still, you could use a `switch()` statement:

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))     
{
    switch($username)
    { 
        case 'operations':
        case 'finnce':
            header("Location: view3.php");
            break;

        case 'Analyst':
            header("Location: Analyst.php");
            break;
    }
}           

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid userID or password ');window.location=\"home.html\";</script>";
```

Please also be advised that the `mysql_*` family of functions is now deprecated, and should not be used in new code. You should instead look at [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning values to variable `$username` instead of comparing the variable to string. Try with :

```
if($username=='operations')
{
   header("Location: view3.php");
}

if($username=='finance')
{
   header("Location: view3.php");
}

if($username=='Analyst')
{
   header("Location: Analyst.php");
}
```